# How to have PRTG Server running beside Apache?

Tags: web-server, network-monitoring

We used to work with a local Apache instance (WAMP) as a development environment, but we installed recently a PRTG server on the same machine, so it listens to the same port, as it is a web-based tool.

We are not able to reach our Apache server anymore as web requests on the server IP keep going to PRTG.

I changed the PRTG listening port to 8080 so that we would have 2 web servers listening to 2 dfferent ports.

It doesn't seems to work well: when I try to reach xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 with a browser (Firefox, Chrome) it instantly changes to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080, and I get to PRTG home page.

Why does it changes from what I requested ? Should I use a totally different non-standard port ? What solutions do I have ?

Comment: You should really take this up with PRTG support.

Answer (score 1):

there are two potential causes to be checked first:

1. Set PRTG on port 8080 but with HTTPS since there is a forwarding to port 80. See [also this KB post](http://kb.paessler.com/knowledgebase/en/topic/5373-prtg-blocks-port-80-although-i-m-using-ssl-on-port-443-how-to-free-port-80).
2. It is "only" hit 80 on localhost/127.0.0.1 port, it is the report generator in PRTG, you [can that solve with this](http://kb.paessler.com/knowledgebase/en/topic/17-how-to-change-the-port-used-for-report-generation).

Bonus Solution: Go to "Windows Service Management Console" and make sure to start the PRTG web server after the Apache. PRTG will only take ports that are not already taken by the Apache.